# How to check the history of processes

Tags: debian, logs, embedded, beagleboneblack, rc.local

I'm using Debian running on a BeagleBone Black. I have a script which is supposed to execute when the system starts. The script then should run a python script. I add the command to run this script inside /etc/rc.local which is supposed to execute it on startup.

However it is not running when the system starts. I don't know if it never executed or it started to execute and then terminated.

Is it possible to get a log history of processes which ran in the past on Debian so I can know.

Comment: The best way to facilitate this sort of historical retrospection is for the process to write to a log file, or to have `rc.local` do so when the script is run.

Comment: The most basic debugging technique is to insert simple print/echo statements and see if and when they are executed. Output to a log file if needed.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Yes i've tried that and it seems that my script is never executed. I thought that by adding commands to rc.local, they get executed aromatically on start-up ?